# Set Application Pool name in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, msdeploy

In My asp.net Core I want to set application pool name so that when I deploy/publish to IIS it uses that application pool name instead of default? Is that possible? Is there an attribute can be used in the .csproj file or in Startup file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use webdeploy to achieve your requirement.  You could firstly create a web deploy package in the application and then run below command to set the application pool name.

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -dest:auto -enableLink:AppPoolExtension -source:package="C:\Package\Package.zip" -setParam:"Application Pool"="Reports"
```